Op amp as reactive components
Recently I saw a circuit made with op amp and resistors and capacitor which was working as a circuit with "negative capacitance". What does negative capacitance mean? Is it possible to make such kind of circuits? Can the same be applied to circuits with negative resistances or inductances? I am really confused about the word negative here. Plz someone help me out.
This is the circuit which i am talking about.


Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Well, analyze the response of that circuit and compare with a capacitor.

@Qmechanic Since this is a purely "conceptual" question it probably is appropriate for this forum although it originates in EE. Hint for the question: calculate the input impedance, and notice that it is proportional to the negative of the feedback impedance (here a capacitor).

I'm not an EE, but I think your circuit is a simplistic example of something that the EEs call a "gyrator." The practical use is in electronic filter designs where an inductance is needed. Physical capacitors hew much closer to ideal behavior than physical inductors do. In certain applications (again, especially, in electronic filters) a gyrator can be used to simulate an inductor that behaves more closely to the ideal than a real inductor could do.

This is all to do as to what your circuit looks like to anything which is connected to the input terminals.

If you do the analysis you should find that the input impedance of this circuit, $Z_{\rm I} = \dfrac v i = \Large{\bf -} \,\dfrac{1}{j\omega C}$, which means that the voltage is leading the current by $90^\circ$ whereas for a capacitor you would normally expect the current to be lagging the voltage.
You can set this circuit up in Spinning Numbers and use the $\fbox{TRAN}$sient button running over $2\,\rm \mu s\, (2u)$ to observe the phase change.

I chose the value of $159\,\rm pF$ for the capacitor so that its impedance at $1\,\rm MHz$ would be $1\,\rm k\Omega$.
If the capacitor is substituted with a resistor then $Z_{\rm I} = \dfrac vi = -\,R$ and there is a $180^\circ$ phase difference between current and voltage.


Thanks a lot
